# Spiltting one matrix into two matrix based on "NA"

Tags: r, matrix

Now I have to split this matrix into two matrix based on the column with "NA" values, one with all "NA" and other without "NA".

Input:

```
>k
       a    u         v
[1,] "10" "mature"    "MIMAT0000062"
[2,] "20" "stemloop"  "NA"
[3,] "40" "mature_2"  "MIMAT0000043"
```

Output should be like,

```
>k1
       a    u         v
[1,] "10" "mature"    "MIMAT0000062"
[2,] "40" "mature_2"  "MIMAT0000043"

>k2
       a    u         v
[1,] "20" "stemloop"  "NA"
```

Is there any function to do it?

Comment: A real NA is without any quotes and using a character `"NA"` is not much helpful for you.  What if one of the NA is in first row of 'u' column?  Or is it only specific to 'v' column?  For this case, `lapply(split(seq_len(nrow(k1)),is.na(k1[,3])), function(i) k1[i,,drop=FALSE])`  (assuming you have real NAs)

Comment: "Is there any function to do it?" 
Yes, there is: `is.na()`

Comment: @akrun I think just `split(as.data.frame(k), is.na(k[, 3]))` should do if OP is fine with a `data.frame` structure within the list

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, it will work.  I just thought to keep it as a matrix (though it is unnecessary even from looking at the input data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the matrix 'k' as follows:

```
k1 <- k[which(rowSums(is.na(k))==0),]
k2 <- k[which(rowSums(is.na(k))>0),]
```

The trick is, that TRUE and FALSE are interpreted as 1 and 0, respectively.

Comment: This works good. But when I want split based on one particular column, it fails. Because it checks for any one NA (even if any other column is NA, it splits). In that case, `k1 <- k[which(is.na(k[,3])==0),]` and `k2 <- k[which(is.na(k[,3])>0),]` works good. Basic idea is same.